# How to get the debugger to stop at the right place in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I trace code in the PyCharm debugger, and an error occurs, the next thing the debugger is showing me is the parent method and if I keep stepping, it just walks back up the stack to eventually print me an error.

Is there a way to get the debugger to tell you there is an error where/when the error happens instead of sending you to the parent? (like it pretty much every debugger in any language)

To illustrate, if I have the following calls:

func1 -> func2 -> func3

and I'm tracing code in func3; if an error happens, the next step is the return to func2, then if I step, return to func1, then an error message is printed in the console.

Comment: It seems to me that you described general debugger behavior. After an error was encountered in a particular line of code, if the error wasn't handled, the only way for next step is up in the callstack. Stop at the line preceding the one throwing the error (either by manual step or breakpoint), if you want to inspect the state when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

That feeling of "next step" returning to the parent function instead is because an exception is currently propagating. You are being bubbled up until an exception handler is found.

You should let the exception propagate, get the stack trace, then place a breakpoint at the raise statement

Optionally, using the debugger to execute `import logging; logging.exception('give me mah exception!")` or similar command may give you the current exception.

Note that if you are stepping over a function call, and that function raises an exception, you won't have, by default, a stop on the inner statement that raises. You can configure this in Run > View Breakpoints, however, as far as i know, you can't distinguish between 'an exception that is raised and caught internally' in the statement you are stepping over and 'an exception that is raised but not caught internally'.

Comment: that makes sense that the exception is walking up the callstack, but what doesn't make sense, according to me, is why isn't the debugger showing me the exception where it happened? or that a pycharm issue, or more general to python? I haven't seen that with any other language/debugger; in fact I'd say it's generally the opposite where the debugger stops code right there, unless there is an exception handler.

Comment: If you are stepping over a function call, if that function call raises the exception, you won't have, by default, a stop on the inner statement that raises. You can configure this in `Run > View Breakpoints`, however, as far as i know, you can't distinguish between 'an exception that is raised and caught internally' in the statement you are stepping over and 'an exception that is raised an not caught internally'.

Comment: I have tried to set this (https://imgur.com/a/U3ap7Oi) following the description on this page: https://joelmccune.com/pycharm-debugging-stop-on-unhandled-exceptions/  I see that there are a few posts dedicated to stop on unhandled exceptions, but none seem to show a working solution.

Comment: On your screenshot, you need to tick the 'on raise' checkbox.

Comment: I tried, but then I can't even load any libraries because of the prevalence of code like: try:
    __NUMPY_SETUP__
except NameError:
    __NUMPY_SETUP__ = False

Comment: yes, that's the major problem with attempting to block on every raise. I would step up until the problematic statement, enable breakpoint on exception, then remove it. But all this seems to feel very convoluted when you could just get the exception stacktrace, get the line that raises the exception, and place a manual breakpoint. Can you link the exception stacktrace?

Comment: it's not about a specific exception, but rather that the workflow in python seems quite painful compared to the other languages because of that. Since nothing is statically typed and libraries are quite poorly documented (compared to c++ and c# at least), there is a lot of trial and error (dealing with Pandas right now) that involve a bunch of exceptions in the debugger. I was hoping for a smooth workflow